# Drowning Squirrel

Tags: mathematics, geometry, optimization, strategy

On a super foggy day, a squirrel falls from a tree into a swimming pool. Due to fog, it cannot see any bank of the pool, unless it touches the bank. It is aware that the swimming pool is in the shape of an equilateral triangle with side length $20\sqrt{3}$ meters, but has no idea where its current location is within the pool. The squirrel is capable of attaining a maximum swimming speed of $1$m/s. If it does not get onto land within $T$ seconds, it will eventually die by drowning.

For $T=20\sqrt{3} = 34.641...$ seconds, the squirrel has an escape strategy:

> The squirrel can escape by swimming in a straight line in any direction. It is guaranteed that squirrel will reach a bank in $t<20\sqrt{3}$ seconds and save its own life

Question:

**Can the squirrel escape when $T = 30$ seconds?**

Bonus:

> For what minimum $T$ does the squirrel have an escape strategy?

Comment: You said, “Unfortunately, the squirrel cannot swim, yet still is capable of attaining a maximum swimming speed of 1 meter/second.”  If the squirrel cannot swim, how can it achieve a swimming speed of 1 meter/second?

Comment: @WillOctagonGibson Good Question :) Apologies for my bad english, if possible someone suggest a good synonym for "swimming". What I meant was, when it comes to near-death experiences, animals tend to go beyond their capabilities...squirrel might try something or another, but according to the puzzle it can never reach a speed greater than 1 m/s inside the pool.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The optimal solution has length

> $20 \sqrt 3 * 3 \sqrt{21}/14 = 90 \sqrt 7 / 7 = 34.0168...$ meters

So, can the squirrel escape when T=30
seconds?

> No, it can't.

This problem is called [Bellman's lost in a forest problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%27s_lost_in_a_forest_problem), and for an equilateral triangle, the optimal solution was found by Besicovitch in 1965. It is explained in detail in [this document](http://wardsattic.com/math/BellmanForestProblem/BellmanForestProblem.pdf) on page 34 by John Ward. Besicovitch's solution is as follows:

> Move in a zigzag path, with 3 equally long segments. Go straight for $x = 30 \sqrt 7 / 7 \approx 11.34m$, then turn right by an angle of $2 \arcsin(1/\sqrt{28}) \approx 21.8 \deg$. Go straight again for $x$ meters, then turn left by the same angle. Go straight again for $x$ meters.

Here's a picture:

> [image: ![Picture of Besicovitch's optimal zigzag path]]

Besicovitch's solution was proven optimal by Coulton and Movshovich in 2006.

Comment: oh wow only a tiny improvement on the naive solution.

Comment: @isaacg This is new for me, I was too coming up with a similar strategy, where I was trying 30 - 45 deg deviation. The proof given by Coulton and Movshovich seems extraordinary.

Comment: It is probably better for the squirrel not to think and just swim straight, rather than stop to think, and sink before it figured out what to do.

Answer (score 1):

The below is wrong because the unproven "intuitive" lemma I used is wrong even for very simple paths. See other answer.

Wrong answer begins here:

*The below uses one property of "well-behaved" paths which is intuitive but not easy to prove rigorously. If that bothers you consider this answer valid only for squirrels that swim along something like spline paths or even piecewise linearly (finite number of pieces.)*

Assuming the squirrel has no knowledge of their position nor orientation and that it is only interested in strategies that given T work in 100% of the possible initial conditions

> the described strategy is already optimal.

As the squirrel doesn't gain any positive information before it reaches the shore a strategy is just a fixed path. And a successful strategy is a fixed path that does barely or not at all fit into the triangle. Equivalently, a fixed path whose smallest circumscribed regular triangle is no smaller than the given one.

Sketch of proof

As announced I will gloss over one tedious technicality:

For any orientation there is a minimal circumscribed regular triangle each side of which touches the path. We are interested in the order in which the path visits the three sides as a function of orientation. Intuitively, if the path is not too crazy (for a suitable concept of non-craziness) we'd assume that this function is mostly constant but occasionally multi-valued. Because the order has to cyclically shift every 120° we'd conclude that there must be an orientation where one side is touched first and last and the other two in between.

Proving this rigorously for as wide a class of paths as possible is as far as I can tell quite technically demanding which is why I won't do it.
Perhaps someone more talented than I can find a proof of the property maybe using compactness.

Anyway, assuming we can use this the original problem becomes rather simple:

> Circumscribe regular triangle, designate points X0,Y,Z,X1 on the path which touch (in that order) sides x,y,z,x of the triangle. Split he path into P0,P1,Pm, the bits before X0, after X1 and in between. Find the images x^y, X0^y and P0^y of x,X0 and P0 mirrored on y and x^z,X1^z and P1^z of x,X1 and P1 mirrored on z. Observe the path has the same length as the partially mirrored path P0^y+Pm+P1^z whose length is at least the distance X0^y X1^z which is no shorter than x, i.e. the side length of the triangle.